# Integration of Kafka in Web Application

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a java based web application which is using 2 backend database servers of Microsoft SQL (1 server is live database as it is transactional and the other one is reporting database). Lag between transactional and reporting databases is of around 30 minutes and incremental data is loaded using a SQL job which runs every 30 minutes and takes around 20-25 minutes in execution. This job is executing an SSIS package and using this package, data from reporting database is further processed and is stored in HDFS and HBase which is eventually used for analytics.

Now, I want to reduce this lag and to do this, I am thinking of implementing a messaging framework. After doing some research, I learned that Kafka could solve my purpose since Kafka can also work as an ETL tool apart from being a messaging framework.

How should I proceed? should I create topics similar to the table structures in SQL server and perform operations on that? Should I redirect my application to write any change happening in Kafka first and then in Transactional database? Please advise on usage of Kafka considering the mentioned use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a couple ways to do this that require minimal code, and then there's always the option to write your own code.

(Some coworkers just got finished looking at this, with SQL Server and Oracle, so I know a little about this here)

If you're using the enterprise version of SQL Server you could use Change Data Capture and [Confluent Kakfa Connect](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/index.html) to read all the changes to the data. This (seems to) require both a Enterprise license and may include some other additional cost (I was fuzzy on the details here. This may have been because we're using an older version of SQL Server or because we have many database servers ).

If you're not / can't use the CDC stuff, [Kafka Connect's JDBC support](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-jdbc/docs/index.html) also has a mode where it polls the database for changes. This works best if your records have [some kind of timestamp column](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc/issues/204), but usually this is the case.

A poll only mode without CDC means you won't get *every* change - ie if you poll every 30 seconds and the record changes twice, you won't get individual messages about this change, but you'll get one message with those two changes, if that makes sense. This is Probably acceptable for your business domain, but something to be aware of.

Anyway, Kafka Connect is pretty cool - it will auto create Kafka topics for you based on your table names, including posting the Avro schemas to Schema Registry. (The topic names are knowable, so if you're in an environment with auto topic creation = false, well you can create the topics manually yourself based on the table names). Starting from no Kafka Connect knowledge it took me maybe 2 hours to figure out enough of the configuration to dump a large SQL Server database to Kafka.

I found additional documentation in [a Github repository of a Confluent employee](https://github.com/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-cdc-mssql) describing all this, with documentation of the settings, etc.

There's always the option of having your web app be a Kafka producer itself, and ignore the lower level database stuff. This may be a better solution, like if a request creates a number of records across the data store, but really it's one related event (an Order may spawn off some LineItem records in your relational database, but the downstream database only cares that an order was made).

On the consumer end (ie "next to" your other database) you could either use Kafka Connect on the other end to pick up changes, maybe even writing a custom plugin if required, or write your own Kafka consumer microservice to put the changes into the other database.

Comment: Thank you for the valuable suggestions. I am using Enterprise version of SQL Server 2016, so CDC can work in my case. But polling method can also work since I have currentTimeStamp in the form of ModifiedDateTime column which gets updated with every change. I will check both the options. Thank you once again for your help :)

Comment: I followed the links provided by you but I could not find a way to connect Kafka with SQL Server to follow polling approach. In the list of Confluent JDBC Connectors, connectors are available for almost all the databases but could not find any for SQL Server. Do you have any useful link/blog which provides any information or steps on using polling approach?

Comment: In my experience and tests you just use the JDBC jar for MSSQL, add it to the Kafkan Connect plugin path, and specify the connection URL jdbc:mysql://